# JavaScript window.print() gives blank printout

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have an HTML-page with some data in table format, and this code:

> ```
>     function printme()
>     {
>         window.print(); 
>         self.close();
>     }
>
>
> <body onload = "javascript:printme()">
> ```

With this, I can get printout from all browsers except one version of IE8 (8.0.7601.xxxxx), which prints a blank page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you care? If its some vague version and 7602 works, thats a very small audience, or do you mean IE8 in general?. Make sure your not in compatability mode, that can mess things up.

Comment: i should, since one of my customer is very specific on that...unfortunate :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem may be caused by closing the window before the page is printed, causing the memory of the page to be freed and resulting in a blank print.

Also, why do you use `window.print` and `self.close` when `window == self` in this context?

Answer (score 1):

i face the same issue often with IE, try this define it in header may be solve your issue.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `javascript:` prefix for events like `onload`, as they are expecting Javascript anyway.

Generally, `javascript:` is only needed for `<a href="javascript:...` (some other things as well, but that's the most common one).

The most likely problem is that IE8.0.7601... for some reason has a quirk which means it doesn't just ignore it, whereas other browsers and other versions of the same browser handle it without any problem.

Comment: though i remove javascript same problem :)